# What is the best way to prevent overlapping events in an MVC EF App?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have an MVC3 application using EF Database First. The application records various events related to a car. The events are not allowed to overlap. Events are created and added from a standard set of CRUD screens based on ViewModels. They are then added to the context via a service that just inserts them via the event repository.

People are creating hire periods for a car. Therefore I need to prevent the car having overlapping hire periods as only one person can hire a car at once.

What is the best way to validate that events can not be created that are overlapping? Where is the best place to put this logic. I am assuming in the domain layer so the core logic can be re-used. Does this belong on the repository or is it something that should be implemented on the entity itself? It is a multi-user system so I need to prevent two people adding events at the same time causing overlap issues.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Graeme

Comment: I think, we need more details, what do yuou mean by having overlapped events. In a web app, it's normal that 2 users to do the same thing. Do you want to ensure that 2 users can't send the same event, where the event is a domain concept and not a .net one?

Comment: I think this is the perfect case to apply the Domain Events and the Event Sourcing patterns. Both Udi Dahan and Greg Young have lots of posts and presentations about it.

Comment: Updated to give details of the domain

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping events"?

Comment: Events have a start date and an end date. No two events should occupy the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think a basic unique constraint in the database is enough for that. If it happens that 2 users book the same car, then the database should refuse the transaction because it will violate the constraint. I think the key can be placed on a Booked  column or smth.

The db will thorw an exception, the repository should catch it and eventually rise the domain event OverlappedBookingEvent which will be handled probably with an error message for the user 'We're sorry, but in the mean time someone else booked that car'.

Although is a business rule, I think this check has to be made at most at the repository level, since is a persistence related rule and ultimately only the database can enforce it.

Comment: Wouldn't the DB have to get all hire events (with start date and end date) and ensure that they don't overlap?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx

Comment: So is the only place that this can be validated in the DB. I guess peoples context don't share context so two people could at the same time add hires overlapping if we don't enforce at the DB level?

Comment: Any request is independent and yes, it might happen 2 users to book the same car at almost (1 milisecond away) same time. The db is the last guardian for data integrity.